# MySQL user table possibly corrupt?

Tags: mysql

Having an issue logging in to a MySQL instance. If I load it with skip-grant-tables and get in, I'm wondering if this is a problem...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8xtt.png)

I'm no dba, but this looks all kinds of messed up. Even after resetting the root password, I was still unable to login, so I created the root2 user, to which I was still unable to login with as well.

Is this table possibly corrupted? If so, is there a way to repair it? And if not, how can I recover this instance and fix the root login?

Mentioned above.......

Comment: Oh man are you doing MySQL work from the command line and not using MySQL workbench instead?  I mean you can do that, but its like using notepad to add up things from an excel file, it can work its just easier with a few right clicks.   Would be much easier to investigate the tables using it.   Download here ->https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

No not corrupt just encrypted.
You can't read that thing using a CLI command, try PhpMyAdmin or a speical software to read your database

Comment: I'm not referring to the passwords. I'm referring to the table, look at the formatting. The first line has random characters on it. The "root" user line doesn't actually say "root", it says Fq0oot then there's a random line break in it.

Plus the fact that I can't login with a newly created user, nor the root user once the password was reset on it.

Comment: Just refresh and check what I said again, I edited it again!

Comment: Note - see my comment above this one, don't use phpmyadmin .. use mysql workbench .. UNLESS you are forced to use phpmyadmin because its a hosted site and you dont have full control.

Comment: Ok thanks, long as that's not an issue then, guess my proble must be elsewhere!